# How to get a string input from stdin that has leading white space in C?

Tags: c, string, input, whitespace, stdin

Need a solution to get input string start with spaces?

I know a method to include space in input

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", s);
```

But its working only for space between words.
I need a solution for string starts with spaces.
And I also need the starting spaces in the variable

Comment: May I ask why the leading white space is required to be contained in the string?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio 
Its actually for the problem solving in online judge.

Comment: @user3121023
```scanf("%[^\n]", s);```
The starting space is ignored by this. :/

Comment: @AzizAhmed `scanf("%[^\n]", s);` does **not** ignore starting space.  Instead, use of a prior  `scanf("%[^\n]", s);` left the `'\n'` in `stdin` and `scanf("%[^\n]", s);` quit due to that `'\n'`.  Save yourself grief.  Do not use `scanf()` until you know why it is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a *line* of user input, use `fgets()`.

```
#define S_MAX_LENGTH
char s[S_MAX_LENGTH + 2];
if (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)) {
  s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0'; // Should code want to lop off a potential trailing \n
  ....
```

---

Do not use `scanf("%[^\n]s", s);` nor `gets(s);`.  They suffer from buffer overflow and other issues.

Comment: Furthermore, the trailing `s` in `"%[^\n]s"` is incorrect.