# Using an empty space in the guard of an if statement for an Array in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, if-statement, space

I'm taking my fist steps in programming and i was trying to make a program that takes as imput your **username** and and prints it out as output.
I wanted to implement an **if statement** that triggers when you imput **spaces instead of characters inside the scanf**, but i can't seem to get it working? is it possible to do or is it impossible for an array of characters?
Thaks for your help!

```
char username[20]; //declares a 20 chars array for the username to be stored

printf("\nPlease input your Username\nUsername:"); //asks for the username
       
scanf("%s", &username); //inserts username inside array "username"
        
if(username == ' '){  //supposedly the guard to my if 
                   
            printf(("invalid imput"));
        
}

printf("%s",username);
```

Comment: `%s` always reads a word into the variable. It will never put a space there.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &username)` invokes *undefined behavior* because `char(*)[20]` is passed where `char*` is expected. the `&` should be removed.

Comment: So how can i stop my program when a space is given as imput? If i keep pressing space or enter it keeps going forever without recognising it as imput.

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks, that fixed one of the warnings! I don't know why but it still doesn't trigger the if function with a space even with this edit

Comment: As @Barmar has already said, using `scanf("%s"...` will never collect the leading space.  You will have to use a different method to read from `stdin`.  A [method to do that is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60269590/645128).